# jquery interate array and match to values in html table and fill in column

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to read through array. Match employee number with table, and fill in bonus value in table on match.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>    
<script>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    // note that employee may get 0,1, or more bonuses
    myArray = 
     {"employees": [      
        {"employee": "1231", "bonus":100},      
        {"employee": "1232", "bonus":200},      
        {"employee": "1233", "bonus":300}      
        {"employee": "1233", "bonus":33}      
      ]
    }

    $.each(myArray.employees, function(index) {                    
    console.log(this.employee);
       // having problem here... 
       $("#myTable:has(td:contains(this.employee)").each(function () {   
       console.log("found");
       // then write to 2nd cell in table next to employee#
       // assume that employee number in table is unique 
       });  
    });   

});     
</script>


<table id='myTable' border='1px'>
<tr>
  <th>Employee</th>
  <th>Bonus</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1232</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1231</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would loop through the table each time

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // note that employee may get 0,1, or more bonuses
    myArray = 
     {"employees": [      
        {"employee": "1231", "bonus":100},      
        {"employee": "1232", "bonus":200},      
        {"employee": "1233", "bonus":300},     
        {"employee": "1233", "bonus":33}      
      ]
    };

    $.each(myArray.employees, function(index) {     
        var emp=this.employee;
        var bonus=this.bonus;
        $('#myTable td').each(function(){
            if($(this).text()==emp){
                console.log('found');
                $(this).next().text(bonus);
            }
        });
    });   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='myTable' border='1px'>
<tr>
  <th>Employee</th>
  <th>Bonus</th>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>1232</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1231</td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<table>
```